# How do I get DBeaver to do a DB2 UPDATE via Cursor

Tags: db2, cursors, dbeaver

The following query works when run from the console via db2 command. But fails when running via DBeaver.

```
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
  FOR R AS C CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS INDEX, ID
    FROM A_TABLE a
    WHERE a.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
    ORDER BY a.ID
  DO
    UPDATE A_TABLE SET A_COL = 1 WHERE ID = R.ID;--
    IF MOD(R.INDEX, 100) = 0 THEN
      COMMIT;--
    END IF;--
  END FOR;--
  COMMIT;--
END;
```

DBeaver gives the following result

> SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "WHERE ID = R.ID".  Expected tokens may include:  "<psm_semicolon>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: `;--` for an in-block statement terminator only works in the CLP. You need to choose a different terminator _for the block_ and configure your client accordingly

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio Do you know how to do this for DBeaver?

Comment: @Lennart will make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mustaccio points out, you need to change your statement terminator. In DBeaver you can do that by:

1. Right-click on the data source and choose "Edit connection"
2. In the leftmost frame at the bottom, there is SQL Processing
3. Check the Datasource checkbox

[image]

Now you can alter the statement delimiter

Comment: Thanks @lennart I'll accept the answer as a workaround. I don't think it is possible to change the 'in-block' terminator this solution changes the 'regular' terminator. I changed "Statements delimiter" to @, "Ignore native delimiter" and "Blank line is statement delimiter" is checked, then my statement works by replacing only the last ; to @ or by leaving a blank line

Comment: Yes, the statement separator inside for example a procedure can not be changed, it has to be; One therefor change the statement terminator to something different, I usually choose @ for this